# Reencoding a file with "Encode::from_to" or "PerlIO::encoding"

Tags: perl, encoding

Between `Encode::from_to` and `PerlIO::encoding`, what's the preferred way to reencode a file within a perl script?

This uses [`PerlIO::encoding`](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO/encoding.html)

```
use warnings FATAL => 'utf8';
open(my $f1, "<:encoding(iso-8859-1)", "infile");
open(my $f2, ">:encoding(utf-8)", "outfile");
print $f2 $_ while <$f1>;
```

Or, should I use [`Encode::from_to`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Encode.html) or is there a better way?

It seems that the first option, with `PerlIO::encoding`, would support not-slurping the file into memory.

Are there any downsides to using that method?

Comment: As phrased, this question is primarily opinion-based. Please provide the criteria which define what solution would be best for you rather than asking us for our preferred ways of doing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show what you intend to do with [`Encode`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode), but the generally-accepted best practice is to work with Perl's internal coding (basically UTF-8, but you don't need to know) and apply the conversions to input and output file handles accordingly

I don't understand where you got the idea that using a PerlIO layer would affect slurping a file. Maybe you're getting confused with line endings, but even so there should be little difference

If you think you must read the entire file into memory then you should think again. It is almost always best to keep state variables across single lines, or perhaps to modify Perl's input record separator `$/` to read multi-line records

Nothing will affect the decoding or encoding of file data unless you are misusing it

Comment: I say in the question that I'm looking to reencode a file (something on disk). `Encode::from_to` requires the whole file to be in memory (not accepting file handles). It looks like I can use PerlIO to avoid that.

Comment: *"`Encode::from_to` requires the whole file to be in memory"* Where did you get that idea? It isn't true at all, and the documentation certainly doesn't say so. You can convert a character at a time if you wish. There would be a problem if you were converting from a multi-byte encoding and you attempt to translate a chunk that ends part-way through a character, but if your record separator is set to a single-byte character (normally LF) then that can't happen with either IS0-8859-1 or UTF-8. I don't know what you mean by *"not accepting file handles"*.

Comment: Ahh I see it does take octets so it can work the same way. Nifty. I stand corrected. My own misconception. (the downvote wasn't me, upvote was). I guess it's just a matter of style then.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: It accepts *only* octets, but even if it used characters there would be no requirement to process the whole file. It's just that characters have no encoding—they are decoded octets—so it is impossible to decode them again.

Comment: Well, the PerlIO method opens the file in character mode for the desired input locale, right? Where as encode `from_to` requires the file opened in bytes mode and expects the encoding of the octet stream in the call?

Comment: This is about encodings, not locales. But I don't see what point you're making. `from_to` requires an encoded octet stream, which may come from a file opened with `:raw` but that isn't necessary. It decodes the octets into characters according to one scheme and then reencodes them to another sequence of octets according to another scheme. You would need to open an output file, again with `:raw`, to write those bytes to disk. I think we agree with one-another but you seem to think there are differences.